# Copying divs in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So here I have an App component where I have rendered the Navbar. I have a toggle function and logic on outside Click using useRef/useEffect. My intentions are when I click on the div where Navbar is located, I want to make a copy of that div/img to specific part of the page, but it's still remains open, and when it's moved I want in that newDiv/copy text/h4 to be removed/dissapear. I would appriciate any help.

```
function App() {

 const [isNavbarOpen, setIsNavbarOpen] = useState(false)
  const navbar = useRef()

  const openNavbar=()=>{
    setIsNavbarOpen(true)
  }

  const closeNavbar=()=>{
    setIsNavbarOpen(false)
  }

  const handleNavbar=(e)=>{
    if(navbar.current && !navbar.current.contains(e.target)){
      closeNavbar()
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('click', handleNavbar)
    return() =>{
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleNavbar)
    }
  },[])

return (
<>
 <div className='smallProjects__container'
   onClick={() => setIsNavbarOpen(!isNavbarOpen)} ref={navbar}>
    <img
      src="./images/icons/folr.png"/> 
      <h4>Navbar</h4>
      {isNavbar? <Navbar closeNavbar={closeNavbar} />: null}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```